# How to set permission dialog for post message on wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I have created application in Facebook. By using Facebook Javascript SDk, I posted message from android phonegap application to facebook wall.But I want to display permission dialog before message post on the wall
(ie) While I am clicking "Allow" button in the permission dialog message should post on the wall,while i am clicking "Don't Allow" button, message should not post on the wall.
My code is:

```
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='all.js'></script>
<input type="text" value="User ID" name="user_ids" />
           <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
            <p id='msg'></p>
    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() 
    {
                    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
                   alert(user_ids);

                    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: user_ids}, function(response) {
                           if (!response || response.error) {
                            alert('Error occured');
                           } else {
                           alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                           }
                   });
      }
   </script>
  </body>
```

the above code is hosted on  server.  In phonegap(index.html) i called the url using window.open method, It will display textbox and button. while i am clicking the button,(get value from textbox)the message should post on the wall 
 how to set permission dialog for this coding or how to pass {perms:'publish_stream'} in FB.api('/me/feed')

Please give me some suggestion /ideas

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I'm getting your question right, but I would suggest this:
First ask permission and in the next step show the send button or send a post automatically - what ever you want. Not both at the same time (I just don't get the concept). Here is some code that might help you a little:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB._https = true;
    FB.init({
        appId : 'APP_ID',
        status : true, 
        cookie : true, 
        oauth : true 
    });

    // Check whether the user is connected to the app
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 'connected') {
            // The user has not authorized the app
            authorizeApp();
        } else {
            // The user has already authorized the app
            var fbuid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                // Check for publish_stream extended permission
                var query = FB.Data.query('select publish_stream from permissions where uid={0}', fbuid);
                query.wait(function(rows) {
                    if(rows[0].publish_stream == 1) {
                        // The user has granted the extended permission
                        postToWall();
                    } else {
                        // The user has not granted the extended permission
                        authorizeApp();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

function authorizeApp() {
    // Redirect the user back after authorization
    var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
    var queryParams = ['client_id=APP_ID', 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI', 'response_type=token', 'scope=publish_stream'];
    var query = queryParams.join('&');
    var url = path + query;
    top.location.href = url;
}

// OR
function authorizeAppInPopup() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // User authorized app
            postToWall();
        } else {
            // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize
        }
    }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir thank you for your reply. How to get and pass text box value to FB.api('/me/feed/','post',{message:''},fuuction(res){}); inside the FB.login function And My coding is working fine for the 1st time,next time it will display error occured.Please tell me solution

Comment: hai, my server name is http://yyy.xxxxx.com. Now I host my code on server In phonegap application call that url using window.open method. In my logcat display error:unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with url file://.../ from frame with url http://yyy.xxxxx.com. how to solve this problem.how to open that url using phonegap application